# Per-directory bash/zsh history log files

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, history

I find I do a lot of work on a project in a set directory. Sometimes — a few months down the track — I need to redo something on that project but I can't remember what I did. I use mercurial or git to track changes to *files* but I want to be able to remember what commands I issued in that directory.

Searching through my shell history is not very informative. I already log everything to my .*_history files, but I want a list of things I did in ~/foo/bar, and not all the other (million) things that I did that week. I probably can't even remember what month I last worked on that particular project.

Does anyone have any ideas how a project directory log file of all shell commands I've used? I'm envisioning a command something like:

> workon myproject

... which would set the shell log file to ~/myproject/.history.log, load the previous history from that logfile, and maybe update my prompt to tell me what directory I'm working on (like e.g. vcprompt to provide version control info).

Is there anything out there like this?

Answer (score 5):

In case you haven't figure this out yet:
what you are looking for is the excellent [virtualenvwrapper](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) package. It is a wrapper around python's *virtualenv* (go figure) and, while it is commonly referred to when taking about python environments, it is actually a very generic tool that satisfies your use case.

## Installation

```
pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

or

```
easy_install virtualenvwrapper
```

and add initialisation stuff into your shell config (`~/.zshrc, ~/.bashrc`)

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export PROJECT_HOME=$WORKON_HOME/projects
export PIP_VIRTUALENV_BASE=$WORKON_HOME
export PIP_RESPECT_VIRTUALENV=true
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

## Usage

```
# create your env
mkvirtualenv my_project

# edit per project hooks
vim ~/.virtualenvs/my_project/bin/{postactivate,preactivate,predeactivate,etc}

# work in this env
workon my_project
```

You also have generic hooks in `~/.virtualenvs/{postactivate,postdeactivate,etc}` that are called every time you `workon any_project`.

So, for example, having the line `export HISTFILE="$VIRTUAL_ENV/bash_history"` in the `~/virtualenvs/postactivate` hook means that the `$HISTFILE` variable will be expanded every time to a different project.

Answer (score 4):

I need this too and I have come up with a version that uses [Bash’s PROMPT_COMMAND variable](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Controlling-the-Prompt):

> The value of the variable PROMPT_COMMAND is examined just before Bash prints each primary prompt. If PROMPT_COMMAND is set and has a non-null value, then the value is executed just as if it had been typed on the command line.

So I say PROMPT_COMMAND="check_for_local_history" in ~/.bashrc.my, where `check_for_local_history` is a function of mine that checks if the last executed command was a directory change, and when that’s true, it checks the new current directory for the .bash_history file. If it’s there, use it as the history file.

Here is the complete gist: https://gist.github.com/gurdiga/dac8d2e7eb3056d6b839

Answer (score 3):

One trick I use for framework of building sub-packages for a product is to use a sub-shell.

For bash you could create a shell script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

export PROJECT_DIRECTORY=$(pwd)

exec bash --rcfile $HOME/.project-bashrc
```

Then in `$HOME/.project-bashrc` you put something like this:

```
source $HOME/.bashrc
export HISTFILE="${PROJECT_DIRECTORY}/.bash_history"
cd "${PROJECT_DIRECTORY}"
```

This also lets you customize the prompt in the `.project-bashrc` file, which can be handy.

I'm not sure how to do the same in `zsh`.  You'd have to override the `ZDOTDIR` variable, I think.  But it'd look similar.

Ciao!

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in a plugin I wrote called *directory-history* for zsh.
Look here: https://github.com/tymm/directory-history

Although it doesn't really fit your *workon myproject* workflow, it should perfectly fit your needs.

It creates a history which includes directories.
When you search through your history, you will first get commands from the directory you are in.
If there are no commands left for that directory it will fall back to a global history and suggest commands used in other directories.

Answer (score 2):

To get a local history file for a directory I added the following line to my bash prompt command.

`if [ -f .local_history ] ; then tail -1 $HISTFILE >> .local_history ; fi`

The command **`touch .local_history`** in a directory then gives me a local history file for all commands executed in that directory, without loosing the main history file. Something similar would work in zsh I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at my logging scripts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/960684/26428). Using one of them, you can keep track of what directory you're in when you issue each command. You can `grep` the log file for the command or other information. I use the long version at home and at work.

Comment: Thanks - I'll have a look into this. Might do something close to what I need!

Answer (score 1):

I've worked in production software houses where we'd just create new users and groups for various functions. New user accounts specifically for configuration management or software builds with varying levels of visibility into other related *functional areas* via group membership and ACL, and the command history performed by say, `cmmgr` would be saved in `~cmmgr/.bash_history`, `bldmgr` related word would be saved in `~bldmgr/.bash_history`, etc.  Unfortunately, to login, a user must own their login directory.  Therefore, a project area was set up on a separate disk altogether.  File creator's ownership showed which *functional area* created the files in the project area, for which the appropriate `.bash_history` may be examined.

The above approach, however, doesn't give you the granularity that you desire, however, it gives you a skeleton that when combined with group membership, a user could switch groups with `newgrp` which effectively creates a new shell and environment, and then use one of the approaches given in the other answers to alter the effective `~/.bash_history` file when *switching hats* to say, `cmmgr` so that a `newgrp` could manage which `~/.bash_history` is used and saved per folder as one enters and exits the new group via the `newgrp` command.  Check out `man newgrp`.  There are some starting off points along these lines in other answers to this question.  These should work with the UNIX group paradigm - most of the nuts and bolts are handled by the shell startup and exit routines as controlled by the `newgrp` invocation.  Check out `newgrp -l`:

```
NAME
     newgrp -- change to a new group

SYNOPSIS
     newgrp [-l] [group]

DESCRIPTION
     The newgrp utility creates a new shell execution environment with modified real and effective group
     IDs.

     The options are as follows:

     -l      Simulate a full login.  The environment and umask are set to what would be expected if the user
             actually logged in again.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want something simple you could have your `.history.log` file as such:

```
#!/bin/cat
some
relevant
commands
```

Then running the file would `cat` those commands you listed in it.
You could also group those commands in separate files by functionality as convention:

```
.howto.datadump
.howto.restart
```

This has the added advantage of working out of the box and not polluting your environment.

Comment: Alternatively you can make use of `README.md` or create other `.md` files per topic and point to them from the readme. That's if you have a markdown friendly source control interface.

Answer (score 1):

There is a shell history extension that allows you to search history and shows you relevant results first based on the current directory, git repository, exit status, and host.

You can install the project here: https://github.com/curusarn/resh
Launch it using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (replaces reverse search).
This is how the search application looks like:

[image: screenshot of the search application]

Disclaimer: I'm the creator of the project and this is shame-less self-promotion

Comment: does this work well with fzf? I use fzf for searching through commands usually

Answer (score 0):

In bash at least, HISTFILE is only consulted at start of shell instance. The per-dir idea won't work here, unless your 'workon' example above creates a shell instance.

Maybe you can look at something like

```
alias workon='script ./.history.log'
```

But script also creates a subshell.

In short, you'll probably need messy levels of subshells to get this to work.

Comment: Damn, I was hoping it'd be something simple. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Here I present two variants, but applicable only to the *Z Shell*.

### Variant 1

This is what I first thought of when reading your question title. With this variant you can switch between two history modes with <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>: *Global* or *local*, where the latter switches to a per-directory history *automatically upon chdir*. The global history accumulates *all* issued commands.

- Demonstration

  ```
  ~ source src/cd_history
  ~ echo global history                                                
  global history
  ~ mkdir foo bar                                                      
  ~ [ALT-h]
  ~                         note the indicator for local history ->   +
  ~ cd foo                                                            +
  ~/foo echo local history in foo                                     +
  local history in foo
  ~/foo fc -l                                                         +
      1  echo local history in foo
  ~/foo cd ../bar                                                     +
  ~/bar echo local history in bar                                     +
  local history in bar
  ~/bar fc -l                                                         +
      1  echo local history in bar
  ~/bar cd ../foo                                                     +
  ~/foo fc -l                                                         +
      1  echo local history in foo
      3  cd ../bar
  ~/foo [ALT-h]                                           
  ~/foo fc -l                                                          
     55  source src/cd_history
     64  echo global history
     65  mkdir foo bar
     66  cd foo
     70  echo local history in bar
     72  cd ../foo
     73  echo local history in foo
     74  cd ../bar
  ~/foo
  ```
- The script (to be included in `~/.zshrc` or to be sourced)

  ```
  # set options for shared history
  setopt prompt_subst
  setopt share_history
  setopt hist_ignorealldups

  # define right prompt as an indicator if local (i.e. per directory) history is enabled
  RPS1=' ${HISTLOC}'
  export HISTLOC=''

  # configure global history file and global/local history size
  export HISTGLOBAL=$HOME/.zsh_history
  touch $HISTGLOBAL
  export HISTSIZE=2000
  export SAVEHIST=2000

  # define wrapper function and key binding to switch between globel and per-dir history
  function my-local-history()
  {
    if [[ -z $HISTLOC ]]; then
      HISTLOC='+'
      chpwd
    else
      HISTLOC=''
      export HISTFILE=$HISTGLOBAL
      fc -A $HISTFILE
      fc -p $HISTFILE $HISTSIZE $SAVEHIST
    fi
    zle reset-prompt
  }
  zle -N my-local-history
  bindkey "^[h"    my-local-history

  # install hook function which is called upon every directory change
  chpwd () {
    if [[ ! -z $HISTLOC ]]; then
      fc -A $HISTGLOBAL $HISTSIZE $SAVEHIST
      export HISTFILE=$PWD/.zsh_history
      fc -p $HISTFILE $HISTSIZE $SAVEHIST
      touch $HISTFILE
    fi 
  }
  ```

---

### Variant 2

Thinking over it again, it seems that per-dir history is too fine grained and you also describe more a per-project history in your question body. So I came up with another variant with a *workon* function to switch between projects. Every project has its own history file `~/.zsh_projhistory_[name]`.

- Demonstration

  ```
  ~ source src/proj_history 
  ~ echo global history                                                                    
  global history
  ~ [ALT-h]                                                              [use workon]
  ~ workon foo                                                           [use workon]
  ~ echo command in project foo                                         [on proj foo]
  command in project foo
  ~ fc -l                                                               [on proj foo]
      1  echo command in project foo
  ~ workon bar                                                          [on proj foo]
  ~ echo another proj, named bar                                        [on proj bar]
  another proj, named bar
  ~ fc -l                                                               [on proj bar]
      1  echo another proj, named bar
  ~ workon foo                                                          [on proj bar]
  ~ fc -l                                                               [on proj foo]
      1  echo command in project foo
      3  workon bar
  ~ [ALT-h]                                                             [on proj foo]
  ~
  ~ fc -l                                                                                   
     31  echo global history
     36  echo another proj, named bar
     38  workon foo
     39  echo command in project foo
     40  workon bar
  ~ ls -1 .zsh_*
  .zsh_history
  .zsh_projhistory_bar
  .zsh_projhistory_foo
  ```
- The script (to be included in `~/.zshrc` or to be sourced)

  ```
  # set options for shared history
  setopt prompt_subst
  setopt share_history
  setopt hist_ignorealldups

  # define right prompt as an indicator if local (i.e. per directory) history is enabled
  RPS1=' ${HISTLOC}'
  export HISTLOC=''

  # configure global history file and global/local history size
  export HISTGLOBAL=$HOME/.zsh_history
  touch $HISTGLOBAL
  export HISTFILE=$HISTGLOBAL
  export HISTSIZE=2000
  export SAVEHIST=2000

  # define wrapper function and key binding to switch between globel and per-dir history
  function my-local-history()
  {
    if [[ -z $HISTLOC ]]; then
      if [[ -z $HISTLOC ]]; then
        HISTLOC='+'
        [[ -z "$HISTPROJ" ]] && HISTLOC='[use workon]' || workon "$HISTPROJ"
      fi
    else
      HISTLOC=''
      export HISTFILE=$HISTGLOBAL
      fc -A $HISTFILE
      fc -p $HISTFILE $HISTSIZE $SAVEHIST
    fi
    zle reset-prompt
  }
  zle -N my-local-history
  bindkey "^[h"    my-local-history

  # function to change project
  workon () {
    if [[ -z "$1" ]]; then
      echo Usage: workon [project name]
      return 1
    fi
    export HISTPROJ="$1"
    if [[ ! -z $HISTLOC ]]; then
      fc -A $HISTGLOBAL $HISTSIZE $SAVEHIST
      export HISTFILE=$HOME/.zsh_projhistory_"$HISTPROJ"
      fc -p "$HISTFILE" $HISTSIZE $SAVEHIST
      touch "$HISTFILE"
      HISTLOC="[on proj $HISTPROJ]"
    fi 
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

After working in one area for awhile.

history >hist1.txt
then later
history >hist2.txt

Sometimes I use the date for the filename.
history >hist20180727.txt

This way there is a recent command history for each directory.